# How do I find the current focussed InternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I am having multiple InternalFrames (JIF) added to a desktop manager. 
How do I know which one has the focus at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha..I didnt see that earlier while searching the docs, pretty simple question. JDesktopPane.getSelectedFrame()